# How to disable selective fields of Android Calendar (app)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I am using following code (copied from [Android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#sync-adapter)) to add events into the calendar. It asks me to choose one of the installed calendar apps for adding. It it possible to disable selective fields in the chosen calendar app? For example, I want user not to modify event title, start and end time for the event.

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable fields or control another app besides your own.

Using an `Intent` to start another `Activity` is a bit like sending something in the mail.  You can't tell the `Activity` what to do with what your are sending.  All you can do is wait for a reply...

However, if you want to get more advanced, you can provide a Calendar UI in your own app, and then update the calender data directly via the `CalendarProvider`

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
...

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
// 
// ... do something with event ID
//
//
```

Comment: I had the same doubts. Thanks for the clarification. :)